# Extracting numeric value from a string of a dataframe's column and replace the string with that numerical value

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

say if columns 'A' contains values for first 3 rows: 4.5 mg, 5.8 mg, 6.3 mg
what i want is: After extracting it should look like: 4.5 , 5.8 , 6.3

Any help?
Beside , i can't figure out how to show my dataframe in stackoverflow. So I am really sorry for the question's body formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with casting to floats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':'4.5 mg, 5.8 mg, 6.3 mg'.split(', ')})

df['new'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'(\d\.\d)+').astype(float)
```

If possible some integers values:

```
df['new'] = df['A'].str.extract(r"(\d*\.?\d+|\d+)").astype(float)
```

---

```
print (df)
        A  new
0  4.5 mg  4.5
1  5.8 mg  5.8
2  6.3 mg  6.3
```

If possible use `split` by first whitespace use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `str` for indexing first values:

```
df['val'] = df['A'].str.split().str[0].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility. Will work if you have a space between the numerical value & the unit.

```
df['val'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]).astype(float)
```

```
print (df)
        A  val
0  4.5 mg  4.5
1  5.8 mg  5.8
2  6.3 mg  6.3
```